# React, Rails, Webpack: Best practice for where to place React.render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I have a rails app currently using webpack to create a `bundle.js` file that is picked up by the asset pipeline.

If I have a page that needs a react component embedded in it, where is the best place to actually call `React.render`? The `react-rails` gem does a great job of doing this unobtrusively, but with webpack I just have an `entry.js` file. Embedding a `<script>` tag in the page seems wrong (and also doesn't work because the JSX isn't transpiled). Is the right approach to jus have a script (probably in `entry.js`) that looks for certain placeholders on the page and replaces them with react components on page load?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you look at the [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/templates/index.html) repo which people have started to use when they begin a new project, the recommended minimalistic way is having a `div` after your `body` and loading the bundled `js` afterwards.